# wsgi без http-ответа

Tags: python, wsgi

Как с помощью wsgi-скрипта выполнить некоторое действие (shell-команду или запись данных формы в файл...) при этом без открытия новой html-страницы?
Вот примерный код:

```
import subprocess
import os

HELLO_WORLD = b"Hello world!\n"
f = subprocess.Popen(["mpc", "play"])

def simple_app(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [HELLO_WORLD]
```

вызывается за счет нажатия на кнопку формы(action="myapp.wsgi")

Comment: в чём конкретно проблема с выполнением действия? Код внутри wsgi-приложения -- это обычный Питон код, например, чтобы записать что-то в файл: `open('имя файла', 'w').write('что-то')`

Comment: ну да, вы правы. с выполнением действий особой проблемы нет. Проблема со второй частью вопроса. На сколько я понял каждый wsgi-скрипт должен включать функцию application, которая возвращает http-ответ, т.е. после выполнения скрипта происходит переход на новую страницу. Именно этого я хотел бы избежать, т.е. просто выполнить действие и все.

Comment: возвращение http-ответа, не означает, что клиент переходит на новую страницу, например, при создании этой страницы (на который мы находимся) происходит несколько http запросов -- ясно что браузер никуда не уходит, получая http-ответы.

Comment: [edit] вопрос, если нужно код добавить.

Comment: а тогда что мне нужно сделать, чтобы эта функция возвращала ничего, но при этом работала?

Comment: Ничего специального делать не надо, это проблема клиента (в браузере). Обновите Ваш вопрос и укажите в каком точно контексте код вызывается.

Comment: Ну вот добавил примерный код

Comment: Похоже вы cgi и wsgi путаете (subprocess у вас только один раз запускается при импорте, а не при каждом запросе). Хотя сути вопроса это не меняет: http-протоколу всё равно как ответы формируются и поведение статичной html  формы также не зависит от того как ответ получен. Отправляйте запрос с помощью JavaScript, вместо формы.

Comment: Надо будет над этим продумать. Кстати, тот скрипт вроде нормально отрабатывает. Благодарю за ответы.

Comment: это не ответы, а комментарии, уточняющие вопрос. Форма для ответа внизу. Когда протестируете решение для вашего случая, можете его как ответ опубликовать, чтобы помочь будущим посетителям с поисковиков. [Это явно поощряется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете отправлять статус `204 No Content`.

```
def simple_app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('204 No Content', [])
    # код выполняющий какие-то действия
    return []
```

При этом клиент (браузер) обязан не менять страницу с которой был отправлен запрос. (Вот [тестовая ссылка, выдающая 204](http://httpbin.org/status/204))

Comment: это не работает в сафари (переход на пустую страницу происходит). UX на браузерах, где работает мог бы быть получше (не очевидно, то ли кнопка не работает, то ли успешно запросы происходят -- немного javascript не повредило бы здесь). Для полноты `return []` в конце можно добавить (пустой ответ).